# On error in profile creation needs cursor scroll on the first error on profile creation page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

HI I have a profile creation page code in which I have several fields to fill at the time of user registering with us.
In this age I made some field necessary to fill at profile creation for that I used Java Script in that  fro example let me take a filed:

```
<div>
 <p><b>Past clients</b></p>
 <p><?php e($form->textarea('UserReference.past_clients',
   array('div'=>false,'label'=>false,'id'=>'past-client' , "class" => "forminput",
   "style"=>"width:675px; height:100px;font-family: Ubuntu, arial, vardana; 
   font-size: 14px; padding:10px 10px 20px;")));?>
 </p>
</div>
```

So to catch field errors I made going id variable concept which is default value null
& use Java script like

```
            var imageName = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#image_name').val());
            if(imageName == 'profile.png')
            { 
                jQuery('#user-image').css('border-color','#F00');
                jQuery('#user-image').css('border-width','<?php e(ERROR_BORDER);?>px');
                jQuery('#user-image').focus();
                if(goingID==''){ goingID = 'user-image'; }
                myImagetip.setContent("Upload photo"); 
                myImagetip.show();
                flag++;
            }
            else
            {
                jQuery('#user-image').css('border-color','rgb(221, 221, 221)');
                jQuery('#user-image').css('border-width','<?php e(NORMAL_BORDER);?>px');
                myImagetip.hide();
            }
```

So whenever user not fills necesary field a error message is coming on that field but the problem is the cursor is not going first error field on page its scrolling few error field above the bottom not the top one if user keep empty that.
Thanks!!

Comment: Your question is not clear... But i can suggest you to use Jquery Form validation plugins for client side validation rather than hard coding your self... I you don't like to use Plugins, then plz make your question clear with examples......

Comment: Thanks @Fazal for response my question like in my code I Have a field suppose Upload image so if the user doesn't upload image so with my this concept of checking upload image field value null then going id which I set for error prospect if it got a error then it shows error on corresponding field but what happening in my code if user doesn't put image in form so it will not save & error message is coming but error scroll not going to top most like on image upload which is my first field for user its just showing lower error  on form if it is there on screen not scrolling to top.

Comment: Could you plz upload few pic of that error with this question? I still can't get your problem....

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to add an css-class to the invalid form fields:

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" class="error" />
<input type="text" />
```

At second, collect all input fields containing css-attribute `error` and determine the element with minimum distance to the top of parent:

```
var lMin = -1;

$.each($('.error'), function() {

    var lTop = $(this).offset().top;
    if(lTop < lMin || lMin < 0)
    {
        lMin = lTop; 
    }
});
```

At last, scroll to the input with the minimum distance to the top of parent:

```
$('#myViewPort').scrollTop(lMin);
```

Here is the fiddle that could help you to handle this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/N62Dq/3/